# Primitive third root of the unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I'm struggling with this question:

> Let us consider $\mathbb{F}_9$. Is it true that a primitive 3rd root of the unit over $\mathbb{F}_3$  is contained in $\mathbb{F}_9$?

I just know that $x=1$ is a root of course of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. I can't find its splitting field because $3$ is not coprime with $3$.  I really don't know how to move in order to answer the question

Comment: $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: I just found it, right after posting. and I was editing. THanks. By the way, how can I answer the question?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $x^2 +x + 1$ is still reducible, since $x=1$ is a root. So, I found out that $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)^3 $ and hence the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_3$

Comment: You click the blue box "Answer your question" and then put your answer there

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Therefore, there is no primitive root of $x^3 -1 $ in $\mathbb{F}_9$. They are all in $\mathbb{F}_3$, which is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_9$. Is everything right?

Comment: @Henry are my last comment right? If so, I can post an answer to the quesiton

Comment: $x^3-1\equiv (x-1)^3\pmod3$

Comment: why does the title say *fourth* root?

Comment: Fix the title. And, by now you may have noticed that $x=1$ is the only solution of $x^3=1$ in **any** field of characteristic three. The conclusion is that in characteristic three there are no such things as roots of unity of order three.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry but I don't understand your last part of the message: why do you say the in char = 3 there is no root of unity of order $3$ ?

Comment: Because $x=1$ is the only solution of $x^3=1$. As you observed, it is a triple root.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that's clear, but why did you say that the order is *not* three?

Comment: The order of an element $g$ of a (multiplicative) group is the smallest positive exponent $n$ such that $g^n=1$. You have shown that $x^3=1\implies x^1=1$, so $3$ can never be the smallest exponent.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Okay, now everything is okay. Many thanks!

Comment: Good ${}{}{}{}$ :-)

Comment: I have the same question: could I argue that such a third root can't exists because $3$ (the order) is not a divisor of $8$?

Comment: I just posted a question about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725108/determine-if-a-4-th-root-of-unity-is-contained-in-mathbbf-9

Comment: @bobinthebox That would only rule out the presence of a root of unity of order three in $\Bbb{F}_9$. In theory, such a root might still exist in another extension field. But that doesn't change the scenery because $3\nmid 26$, $3\nmid 80$ and $3\nmid 3^n-1$ for all $n$.