# Determine if a $4$-th root of unity is contained in $\mathbb{F}_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, finite-fields, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

I have two questions, one of those is the same [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700140/primitive-third-root-of-the-unit), but I'd like to use another argument and I need a check!

The text is:

> i) Is it true that a primitive 3-th root of the unit over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is contained in $\mathbb{F}_9$ ?
>
> ii) Is it true that a primitive 4-th root of the unit over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is contained in $\mathbb{F}_9$ ?
>
> Eventually, find such roots.

---

My attempt:

Let $\mathbb{F}_9= \mathbb{F}_3[x] / (x^2 + 1)$ and let $\alpha = \bar{x}$. I have that $\beta = \alpha + 1$ is a **primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_9$**

i) Let us assume to have such an element $g$ s.t. $g^3=1$, $g \in \mathbb{F}_9$, the candidate primitive root of order $3$. Now, take $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_9$ primitive element. I know that exists $d$ s.t. $g= \beta^d$. So, I obtain $$\beta^{3d} = 1 \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_9$$

and therefore I have $3d = 8$ and hence I would find that $3\mid 8$, which is not possible. Therefore, such a root can't exist.

ii) I know that $\text{ord}_4(3) =2$. Therefore, using again $\beta$ primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_9$ I find: $$4d = 8$$

which implies $d = 2$ and hence  $g=\beta^d=\beta^2 = (\alpha + 1)^2$ is such a root.

Comment: Now the question makes sense. Is the second point okay?7 @ancientmathematician

Comment: The second looks OK, but (i) is still nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to argue by contradiction and looking at the orders for i), because I did not want to use the argument in the other question. Is there any way to use some "order" argument? @ancientmathematician

Comment: You write $3d=8$, which is wrong: what you know at this stage is $8|3d$; from this you can deduce $8|d$, so that $g=\beta^8=1$.

Comment: Yes, because the order of an element divides the order of the (multiplicative) group, so $8|3d$, but this does not help me to prove there's no third primitive root, right?

Comment: Come on, as everyone keeps telling you the only $3$rd root is unity here is $1$, and that's what we have just shown (again).

Comment: Okay, I'm definitely convinced now, thanks for your time @ancientmathematician :)